# modal window will not open

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

I am trying to add a modal window option to my webpage. It is a search page and when clicking on each search result the link will open up in a modal window. So Ive used the code from the page http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial , The modal window wrks everywhere in the page except the jquery template section. my template coding goes like this

```
<script id="srch1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
        <tr><td><div id="title"><a href="#dialog" name="modal" style="text-decoration:none; color:#333333;"><b>${_source.Title}</b></a></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div id="date">${_source.fetchTimeStamp}&nbsp;|&nbsp; ${_source.SourceName}</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div id="content">${_source.Content}</div></td></tr>
</script>
```

so when we click on the title link, instead of opening up in a modal window, the page move backs to top and "#dialog" appears next to the webapge address. Hw cn this be fixed?

The Javascript/jQuery coding goes like this

$(document).ready(function() {

```
//select all the a tag with name equal to modal
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the A tag
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

});

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});         

$(window).resize(function () {

    var box = $('#boxes .window');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    box.css('top',  winH/2 - box.height()/2);
    box.css('left', winW/2 - box.width()/2);

});
```

});

and the plain HTML part

```
<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
Simple Modal Window | 
<a href="#" class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
 <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is fine...it wrks inside the <body> part!! bt when I put the link inside jquery template..it will not open..

Comment: The code and link you posted are rather confusing... try boil it down to what is not working. Does your link have an attribute `name` with value `modal`, is jquery loaded when you click it?

Comment: Ive only pasted the relevant part. I will explain. the html part that Ive added is for the modal window. They are hidden and only comes to display when clicked on search result link. So once I put a search term , I will get the search result and clicking on each link activates a modal window which display the content of that link. the first script part is for the jquery template to display the array which contains the search results..

Comment: and yes I ve an attibute with name modal.. its the first code ive pasted...

Comment: I notice you cache the 'id' value for the element.. why not store the $(id) in a local var as well instead of wrapping it up (making a DOM call) every time?

Comment: Another CSS/HTML5 approach is [http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine, i pasted it into JsFiddle, and its behaving like it should: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dqen/

Could you try to see if you get any JS errors?

---

It might be that the link is inserted after the dom is loaded, and therefore it is not listed. Try using the LIVE function.

```
$('a[name=modal]').live("click", function(){
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the A tag
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
});
```

Comment: yea..it is wrking fine...bt it will not wrk when I put them link inside the a jquery template in head tag..

Comment: <tr><td><div id="title"><a href="#dialog" name="modal" style="text-decoration:none; color:#333333;"><b>${_source.Title}</b></a></div></td></tr>
 this where Ive provided my link

Comment: If thats being outputted to the browser it would seem like there is a problem with the template itself. Are you calling the `$.template(...);` function? If the output is wrong, you are either not compiling it, or there is an error when compiling.

Comment: Im using the .tmpl() function and appending it to the div and I am getting the ouput. when we move the mouse on to each title, it shows the cursor as "hand" as it is a link..but when we click on the link, the modal window will not open, instead since ive specified href as "#dialog", #dialog is appended to the webpage address in the address bar...

Comment: Haha, great! Guess jQuery does load the tmpl into the dom, weird! :)

Comment: Not yet no, hopefully soon :&